# Get all child recrods

Tags: hierarchy, parent-to-child

I have object Sales with self relationship. I want to ger Parents and all Child, but it has  multiple level hierarchy.  To get Parent i just search for recotd with Parent__c = null. To get Child i search by Parent.id. But what to do if there are 999 levels of child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce only allows us to query up 5 levels and down 1 level, so it's fairly obvious that a single query cannot give you a neatly packaged list with multiple levels of embedded children.

If SOQL alone can't do it, then you start looking at what you can do with Apex too.

Provided that you aren't trying to handle more than 50k records (which would have you run into the governor limit on query rows), it's actually quite simple to build a data structure that contains all of the hierarchy.

The idea is that you use a `Map<Id, List<SObject>>`. The Id is the Id of any given record, and the `List<SObject>` is the list of all records that point to *this* one as their direct parent.

```java
Map<Id, List<Account>> parentIdToChildren = new Map<Id, List<Account>>();

// You don't need to worry about the top-level records in the hierarchy, so I won't be including
//   them.
for(Account acct :[SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Account WHERE ParentId != null]){
    // Pretty standard map population pattern
    // If we haven't seen the key of the map, add the key to the map and initialize
    //   the value so we can use it later.
    if(!parentIdToChildren.containsKey(acct.ParentId)){
        parentIdToChildren.put(acct.ParentId, new List<Account>());
    }

    // Our map is guaranteed to have a List in it for this ParentId at this point, so no
    //   need for a null check here.
    parentIdToChildren.get(acct.ParentId).add(acct);
}

// parentIdToChildren now contains the entire hierarchy
// You could enumerate the hierarchy using a recursive method
// Given you know the Ids of the records at the top of the hierarchy, it'd simply be
//   1 - print the current record
//   2 - recursiveCall(parentIdToChildren.get(acct.Id))
```

Comment: Thank you. This works fine.